# Can't login to my SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio if not connected to a WIFI

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, wifi

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my SQL Server Management Studio? Well it doesn't really happen all the time but it is somewhat annoying that I need to open my other WI-FI modem (I am using UTP Cable for my internet connection) and connect my laptop with it just to login to Mgmt Studio.

Here is the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the appropriate name to connect to your server. You may need to add a connection using a fully qualified domain name. The short of the long is this: try pinging the server to be sure that you are using a name that can be resolved by your computer. You may have a name resolution issue is all.

Comment: i dont change the name, i input the password, it didn't go. then i open my wi fi modem, connect, then login, then it goes. so i assume it is not the name issue since i leave it as it is. the only thing i type is the password.